# android studio: Interstitial Ad not show in splash screen activity

Tags: android, admob, ads, interstitial

I'm trying to integrate Interstitial Ad in splash screen activity by using this [tutorial](https://ads-developers.googleblog.com/2014/04/how-to-create-google-mobile-ads-splash.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:%20GoogleAdsDeveloperBlog%20(Google%20Ads%20Developer%20Blog)) .. but the ad not loading.

can anyone tell me where is the problem please?

thanks in advance

here is my code :

```
mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.interstitial_full_screen));
    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener()


{
    @Override
    public void onAdLoaded() {
        if (!interstitialCanceled) {
            waitTimer.cancel();
            mInterstitialAd.show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
        startHomeMain();
    }
});

waitTimer = new Timer();
waitTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        interstitialCanceled = true;
        SplashScreenActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                startHomeMain();
            }
        });
    }
}, 5000);
} // end of onCreate implementation.
```

Comment: I didn’t read through the tutorial, but stick to the Google tutorial for interstitial ads, it’s quite clear and probably just as simple and most important it’s always up to date: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start

Comment: the interstitial ad work good in other emplacement like home page, activities.. but in the splash screen not work. And if i use the some code (acticities code) in the splash screen it work good but i want it to work by using this code